# Proving that $\log(k)$ is irrational if $k\neq 10^n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, logarithms, rationality-testing

How to prove the following? Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$, so that $k \neq 10^n, n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove then, that $\log(k)$ is irrational. I'm fairly new to proofs, so I've taken a look on the internet which gave me the following:

Assume that $\log(k) = \frac{m}{n}$ is rational number, with $m, n$ being positive integers. Then 
$$10^\frac{m}{n} = k$$
$$10^m = k^n.$$
It is obvious that equation does not hold, because $k \neq 10^n$.

Is this a right approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the right approach, but why is it "obvious" that $10^m=k^n$ is impossible?  For instance, $4^3=8^2$ even though $8$ is not an integer power of $4$.  To make this rigorous, you can think about the prime factorizations of $10^m$ and $k^n$.

Comment: So, I take $(5\cdot2)^m$ on the RHS, but what about LHS? I can't make it...

Comment: @AcceleratetotheInfinity Is it possible for any number that does not have a factor of $n$ to be divisible by $n$?

Comment: @AlgorithmsX obviously not.

Comment: Well, what prime factors can $k$ possibly have if $k^n=10^m$?  You can then use this to write down a general form of the prime factorization of $k$ and thus of $k^n$, and use this to prove that if $k^n=10^m$ then $k$ was actually a power of $10$.

Comment: @AcceleratetotheInfinity That fact will remove the integers from possible consideration. You will never have an $n$ and an $m$ such that $a^n$=$b^m$ where $a\neq b$. You can then extend this idea to the rational numbers. For ${\frac a b}^m = {\frac c d}^n$, where $a \neq c$, $b \neq d$, and both $\frac a b$ and $\frac c d$ are legal rational numbers, to be true, $a^m*d^n = b^n*c^n$. You should be able to go from there.